# Atom Hydrogen - multiple kernels after clean python installs

Tags: python, atom-editor, hydrogen

On Windows 7, I have just reinstalled latest 2.7 and 3.6 python versions in a new clean folder, for a completely new dev project, using the windows msi installers. I installed in each installation the iPython packages and in the Scripts folder of each installation I can successfully run 'jupyter kernelspec list' (with or without --json) - the QtConsoles work in each version as expected. I have not added python to my PATH.

I wanted to try out Atom.Hydrogen so installed that/them from the relevant web sites.

All looks good, but when I try to run any python code, errors arise telling me it cannot find any kernels. These focus on not having any kernelspec definition for my python versions.

The Hydrogen errors are:

> No kernel specs found
>
> Use kernelSpec option in Hydrogen or update IPython/Jupyter to a version that >supports: jupyter kernelspec list --json or ipython kernelspec list --json

and

> No kernel for language null grammar found
> Check that the language for this file is set in Atom and that you have a >Jupyter kernel installed for it.

I have tried adding each of the python folders to PATH before running atom, and even though I have confirmed that PATH is updated in a sub-shell Atom/Hydrogen seems to ignore this as it still reports that it cannot run 'jupyter kernelspec'.

The following .bat script shows the correct kernelspec output, but when the jupyter command is replaced with the Atom exe then it finds no kernels:

> set PATH=%PATH%;D:\Python\Python36\Scripts
>
> cd C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.27.1
>
> C:
>
> jupyter kernelspec list

As suggested elsewhere, I created a kernelspecs file (%APPDIR%\Roaming\jupyter\kernels) with both kernels listed, and this seems to be ignored.

I edited .atom/packages/Hydrogen/spec/kernel-manager-spec.js to reflect my kernels in place of the (linux centric) existing definitions in there (which incidentally creates a python 3 entry which points at python 2, suggesting this is not used either), and this also had no effect.

Does anyone know how and where in the Hydrogen config to explicitly set up a kernelspec which includes both my python versions and is actually read by Hydrogen, without reinstalling everything again via Anaconda or virtualenv (which may have similar problems) ?

Where does Hydrogen keep this config information ?

Comment: I also saved the file as a .py and had almost identical errors except it stopped moaning about no kernel for null grammar and started moaning about no kernel for python.